# Google App Engine modules / services app deploy from Eclipse

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin, gae-module

Since a week my Google App Engine project fails to deploy to the Google server.
It is an EAR project (with modules / services) which does not use maven.
I have always deployed it to the remote server using the 'Servers' panel in Eclipse (JEE, or WTP). The Google plugin for Eclipse inserts a drop-down menu in the 'Servers' panel.

The error occurs immediately when I try to deploy. It says:

> 'Executing Google App Engine Remote Operation' has encountered a problem. An internal error occurred during "Executing Google App Engine Remote Operation".

In the details there is a bit more information, namely "java.lang.NullPointerException". Not stack trace, no indication where the NPE happened, no location of a log file.

Does anyone (maybe from Google?) know where to start looking for the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the 'versions' panel in the app engine console, I noticed that the size of my project had shrunk from 18 to 12 MB. Apparently, not all the necessary libraries were deployed. Maybe this was caused by a failed update of the Google plugin?

I removed the Google plugin for Eclipse and re-installed it. Then I reconfigured my project from scratch. The problem has gone away, so it was probably caused by some misconfiguration.

I had to rollback an update that apparently was in progress, in spite of the earlier error. The drop-down menu in the servers panel is useless for rollbacks, since it will always end in an error, doing nothing useful. I had to use `appcfg` from the command-line.

This is not really a solution to the deploy problem I had, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Google plugin on eclipse. As a backup I use the google app engine launcher GUI. Just point it to the project in your file directory and click "deploy".

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that a launcher GUI existed! I am not sure if it handles modules (now called services) in EAR projects?